# vb.net append combobox text at runtime?

Tags: vb.net, text, combobox, runtime

Hi I have a combobox with a list of presets populating it. What I would like is that if a preset is changed (tweeked) that the selected item in the combobox appends the existing text...

as example if the combobox item is original (from form load event) displayed as cube... and I edit the preset that the text in the combobox now displays Cube...(edited)... what i dont want though is a new item added called Cube...(edited) I just want to append the existing item named Cube... to Cube edited...

is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I made this in c# and used the translator to convert it into Visual Basic.
It should do the trick from what i can understand from your question.

```
Public Class Form1

Dim OLDDATA As String

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim myItems = New List(Of String)
    myItems.Add("Hello")
    myItems.Add("World")
    myItems.Add("Cube")

    For Each item As String In myItems
        ComboBox1.Items.Add(item)
    Next

End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Try
        ComboBox1.Items.Remove(OLDDATA)
        ComboBox1.Items.Add(ComboBox1.Text)
        ComboBox1.Update()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub

Private Sub ComboBox1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ComboBox1.Click
    OLDDATA = ComboBox1.Text
End Sub
End Class
```

If you have any trouble with it, let me know and I will do my best to reply to you quickly.
 Happy Coding!